# Angular 11 select binding

Tags: angular, typescript, select, binding

I'm using `Angular 11` and I'm trying to do a very simple thing that is going me mad.

I have this `country.ts` model object:

```
export class Country {
  private id:Number;

  private code?:String;
  private name?:String;
```

}

I have the same `Java Object` at backend level. Now I have an `html` page like following:

```
<div class="country-select">
  <select [(ngModel)]="country" class="form-select form-select-sm" (change)="country_onChange(country)">
    <option [ngValue] = 0>   SELECT COUNTRY</option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of country" [ngValue]="c">{{c.id}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And a matching `.ts` for the page above:

```
......
constructor(
  private airpollService: AirpollService,
) { }

country: Country[];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.airpollService.dataList(this.page).subscribe(success => {
    this.airpoll = success;
  });

country_onChange(selectedCountry:any) {
  console.log(selectedCountry);
}
```

The backend calls works fine.. in my `html` page I see my `select` correctly loaded but when I select a value and `country_onChange()` event is fired it prints `undefined`.

I have tried everything, putting the whole object inside `[ngValue]` putting just the id value.. I have also tried:

```
country_onChange(country) {
  console.log(country);
}
```

In this case it prints all the 66 Object loaded from DB. Can you explain me what's wrong?

I'm forget to add this kind of solution:

```
<select 
  id="filterCountry" 
  [(ngModel)]="filterCountry" 
  name="filterCountry" 
  class="form-select form-select-sm" 
  (change)="country_onChange()"> // I can put everuthing here, nothing works
    <option *ngFor="let c of country" [ngValue]="c">{{c.id}}</option>
 </select>
```

to my `.ts`

```
......
constructor(
  private airpollService: AirpollService,
) { }

country: Country[];
filterCountry: Country; // or any, nothing change

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.airpollService.country().subscribe(success => {
    this.country = success;
    this.filterCountry = this.country[0]; // I have seen this on a example, sound pretty stupid
  });

country_onChange() {.
  console.log(this.filterCountry.id); // print always 1..
}
```

@tmtplayer I have read all this thing on various post.. but there are several way to do it depending on the version.

----------------------------- UPDATE -----------------------------

Sorry is a typing error, I have corrected it. In my code I have `filterCountry` in both side and doesn't work.. I have try with `value` but not with `[value]`. I will try and I let you know. It's really amazing because I have working code, identically to mine, with previous version of Angular (Angular 7) that works.. It's really a shitty language at all!! Does a 11 version of this language documentation exists on internet??

Comment: What are you expecting to be emitted from the `(change)` event?  You're binding the control to a local piece of state that is an array of countries.  You're then populating a dropdown list by iterating through that array.  And on change, you're passing that array back up?  There may be confusion in that your options are of type `Country` where your linking your model to type `Country[]` (which is the same list allowing the presentation of the objects you can select).  Try separating your result from your data defining the options list.

Comment: Have you tried `[value]` ?

Comment: In your code addition above, you have a typo (`filterCountry` in your html, vs `filteredCountry` in your .ts file). Can you confirm that is just in this post, or also in your code?

Comment: Angular is actually a fairly solid, and well-designed framework.  You can find documentation here: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Comment: I think your problem might be re-using the same variable names in your templates. For example your ngModel binding is labelled `country`, while your ngFor is also trying to loop thru `country` I made a minimal stackblitz to demonstrate your use-case https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r9kuvv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In my second example my ngModel is labelled `filterCountry` and then I iterate through `country` and doesn't work anyway. Thanks for your example but I have already made a try with stackblitz and the similar code, with inline list declaration works in `Angular 7` but not in my environment. Fairly solid...

Answer (score 0):

A picture says more than a thousand words....

[image]

Thanks you all guys.